# Count Frequency of subgroup Proc SQL

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to find a way to select a frequency count for rows of a subgroup with no distinct identifiers (well, I guess the distinct identifier is a combination of statuses).  Consider the sample data:

```
data have;
    input Series $ Game Name $ Points;
datalines;
A 1 LeBron 2
A 1 LeBron 3
A 1 LeBron 2
A 1 LeBron 2
A 2 LeBron 2
A 2 LeBron 2
A 2 LeBron 3
A 3 LeBron 2
;
run;
```

Each row here is a shot LeBron took in a game within a series.  I want The series/game summary, with a count for number of shots.  Like this:

```
Series Game Name     Freq Sum 2pt 3pt
A      1    LeBron   4    9   3   1
A      2    LeBron   3    7   2   1
A      3    LeBron   1    2   1   0
```

I have to use Proc SQL here, rather then proc means because I am pulling the data in from multiple tables.  Also, I will have several thousand "Series" and many more "Games" and "Names" so please keep answer general  Here is what I have:

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
    select Series,
                Game,
                Name,
                sum(points) as totalpoints
    from have
    group by 1,2,3;
run;
```

Thanks.

Pyll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No particular reason you couldn't use `PROC MEANS` pulling from multiple tables - you can always create a view (either in SQL or in the data step).  But anyway,

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
    select Series,
                Game,
                Name,
                sum(points) as totalpoints,
                count(points) as numbershotsmade
    from have
    group by 1,2,3;
run;
```

You can also use the `n` function which does the same thing.

`count(points)` will count the non-null points values; `count(1)` will count the total number of rows even if points is null.

Comment: Thanks, Joe.  I'll look into using proc means when multiple tables are involved.  My only experience has been with using the proc on one input table and producing one output table.  Didn't realize it was that powerful.

Comment: what if I want to add two columns for two point baskets and three point baskets? See edited question.  I tried using something like count(case when points=2) as 2pt, but syntax must be wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: nevermind, I got it using sum(case when points=2 then 1 else 0 end) as 2pt